# Responsive width and height for a group of squares

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a grid of 1:1 squares. The user can keep adding squares and I want the size of the squares to be maintained at their aspect ratio but resize accordingly. The tricky part is I want the square to always be visible on the page - that is to say that there is no scrolling and the webpage would be responsive with width and height.

I have created an example that adds a square every second while testing this. However, I am unable to get it working with the height part. I have been able to get it working with the width.

```js
setInterval(() => {
  //  console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('square-container')[0]);
  document.getElementsByClassName('square-container')[0].innerHTML += ("<div class='square'></div>");
}, 1000);
```

```css
.square-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.square {
  position: relative;
  flex-basis: calc(33.333% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: red;
  transition: background 1s;
}

.square::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="square-container">
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

I'm not using any ui libraries like bootstrap, just vanilla html, css and javascript.

Comment: What do you mean "by the height part"?

Answer (score 1):

Use Float instead of wrap. set the square-container display block.

```
<div>
<div id="square-container">
    <div id="square"></div>
    <div id="square"></div>
    <div id="square"></div>
    <div id="square"></div>
    <div id="square"></div>
    <div id="square"></div>
    <div id="square"></div>
    <div id="square"></div>
</div>
</div>

#square-container{
  display: block
}
#square{
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: orangered;
    margin: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input however it's not exactly what I was after, as the container overflows and requires a scroll Agustín Dorado's solution is closer to what I'm looking for but not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest a pure javascript approach?

Basically  just set a inicial value and let javascript do all the calculating every time a square is added.

```js
// Function to resize the squares
function resizeSquares(){
    // Get the squares
    squares = document.getElementsByClassName('square');
    for (i=0;i<squares.length;i++) {
        // Set the width of the square according to the window width
        squares[i].style.width = document.body.clientWidth / squarePerRow + 'px';
        // Set the height of the square to its width to keep the aspect ratio
        squares[i].style.height = squares[i].style.width;
    }
}

// Set initial square capacity for each row
    squarePerRow = 3;

// Inicialize the size of the squares
resizeSquares();

setInterval(function(){
    // Add a square
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML += '<div class="square"></div>';
    // Check if squares exceeds the window
    if(document.body.clientHeight > document.documentElement.clientHeight) {
        // If they do, add one square capacity per row
        squarePerRow = squarePerRow + 1;
    }
    // Resize the squares
    resizeSquares()
}, 1000)
```

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.square {
    background: red;
    border: 5px solid white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: all, 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. However, it's not exactly working that well. it seems quite jumpy but this is the kind of thing I am looking for. I would be fine with a Javascript solution and this is definitely in the right direction.